# PHP: Replace create_function in PHP 8

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, deprecated

I need replace create_function() for something else

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', create_function( '', 'global $Gestor_Cadastros; $Gestor_Cadastros = new Gestor_Cadastros();' ) );

I don't know about this, what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `create_function()` function is considered obsolete as of PHP 7.2 and should be avoided for security reasons. It is recommended to use an [anonymous closure instead](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function() {
   global $Gestor_Registers;
   $Gestor_Registers = new Gestor_Registers();
});
```

Comment: The function does not exist in PHP/8 so it isn't a mere security concern.